# Design a Turing Machine which accepts word with odd length with one in the middle

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

> Design a Turing Machine which accepts word with odd length with one in the middle

for example : $00100\in L,\quad 011\in L$ but $101,11,11011\notin L$

I tried this:

delete the first digit(deleted digit marked with x) and then go right till you see a space, when you walk on the first space (the end of the word) delete the first digit from the right (marked with y) then go left till you see x (loop)

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: What is the second q1 to q2 transition?

Comment: @Bram28 in the bottom its for the first time that I have a "space " i.e the and of the word

Comment: Ah, ok!  So ... can you first just describe (in your post) in words your basic strategy?

Comment: the second: y;y,L its says go left every time that you see y (this is a mark for deleted digit from the end)

Comment: What is the end state?  How does the machine indicate whether it is a 'good' or 'bad' string? I see your basic strategy, replacing with x's on the left and with y's on the right .. but it doesn't seem like you test for that 1 in the middle

Comment: @Bram28 I made a final state from q3 1;1;S     i.e from q3 if you see 1 stay in your place and accept the word

Comment: If you do that from q3 then it will accept 1000011, i.e after putting down the first y and going left from there it would see the 1 and accept ... which it shouldn't.

Comment: This is why I'm stuck

Comment: OK, I gave some pointers for how to change the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy of replacing with x's on the left and y's on the right is fine, but at some point you need to check for that 1 in the middle (and oddness).

So: when you get back to q0 coming from q3, and you see a y, then you must have had an even length string, so then you should reject.

Also: coming from q0: if you see a 0 you should go to a different state than if you see a 1, because that 0 or 1 could be the middle symbol. So: if after replacing that 0 or 1 with an x, and you see a y (or a space, in case your string was just a single symbol) to the right of it, then you should stop, and accept or reject depending whether you just replaced a 1 or 0 (this is why you need two different states.

Here is an updated machine:

[image]